# Visual Studio how to verifying 2 text boxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I was looking if anyone could help me out on writing this simple code. I would like to make it where I have 2 text boxes and one button. In one of the text boxes I would be inputting a sentence. The second text box I would be inputting the same sentence but a little modified where it would have a miss spelling in one of the words. When I hit the verify button it would check both of the text boxes to see if each of the sentences entered are the same. If they are the same then I would get a message "Same". If they are different then I would get a message "different" and it would display where the error is in the sentence by changing the word in red or something like that.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You want community to write the code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for VB that would be:

```
If firstTB.Text.Equals(secondTB.Text) Then
     lblResult.Text = "Same"
     lblResult.ForeColor = System.Colors.WindowText
Else
     lblResult.Text = "Not the Same"
     lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red
End If
```

If you want to compare case insensitive then

```
If firstTB.Text.ToLowerInvariant = secondTB.Text.ToLowerInvariant Then
    ' etc
```

One flaw is that you assume one of them is correct.  Since the control one (the correct spelling) is in a textbox, the user could edit it before clicking a button.  So, either use a label or be sure to set the control on to `ReadOnly = True`

Comment: This is perfect too and the case insensitive is what I was looking for too because if i didn't add this then "Yes" and "yes" are displayed as different

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use.

```
if(<idtextbox1>.text.equals(<idtextbox2>.text)
{
 <idlabel>.text="Same";
}
else
{
<idlabel>.text="different";

}
```

Not sure on how to mark the word red, but I'll search a bit and let you know.